# Proving that convergence with respect to p norm is equivalent to convergence of individual components

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have been provided with question in Functional analysis which is stated as below:
[image: Question]

I also have been provided with a solution which is given by the below picture.
[image: Solution]
Now what they have essentially proved is that all the p norms are equivalent to each other by trying to make it bounded by some constants. **My question is that how does it prove that convergence with respect to p-norm is equivalent to the convergence of individual components.**
*Note I have posted image as I am new to math stackexchange. I know we are supposed to write latex. Please ignore for this time and provide me with proper argument instaed of downvoting the question*

Comment: Hello :) Observe $|x_i|\leq\sum_{k=1}^d|x_k|= \|x\|_1$. If $\|x\|_1<\varepsilon$, then $|x_i|<\varepsilon$ for all $i=1,\ldots,d$. And if $|x_i|<\frac{\varepsilon}{d}$ for all $i=1,\ldots,d$ we have $\|x\|_1=\sum_{k=1}^d|x_k|<\varepsilon$

Comment: @Jochen I am learning this topic for the first time, can you please teach as if you are answering an 18 year old who is learning this for the first time